# Vercel - rewrite route to external page

Tags: hosting, url-routing, vercel

I have a question about rewrite configurations on Vercel, very similar to [this vercel discussion](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/4964). My problem is essentially the same but reverse:
I have a site on vercel (main.vercel.app), and I would like to rewrite different pages to other vercel sites. So what I want is:

```
main.vercel.app/page-a   -->   page-a.vercel.app
main.vercel.app/page-b   -->   page-b.vercel.app
```

When I tried this configuration, it would correctly load the page, but all the assets (page-a.vercel.app/styles.css etc.) would not be loaded:

```json
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/page-a",
      "destination": "https://page-a.vercel.app/"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I tried this configuration, it would redirect all the assets, but not the initial page:

```json
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/page-a(.*)",
      "destination": "https://page-a.vercel.app$1"
    }
  ]
}
```

So what's the correct configuration supposed to be?

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm in the same situation. Did you figure out a way to fix this?

Comment: Any solutions, you found?

Answer (score 1):

What if you try merging the two rewrites?

According to you, one rewrite pattern is correct for the main page, and the other is for all other assets other than the main page. Since `rewrites` is a list and can hold multiple patterns, try merging the two objects and making it something like this:

```js
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/page-a",
      "destination": "https://page-a.vercel.app/"
    },
    {
      "source": "/page-a(.*)",
      "destination": "https://page-a.vercel.app$1"
    }
  ]
}
```